# Push nested object to array

Tags: arrays, json, object

how to push nested json object into array.
This is sample json object. Assume I have 100 GROUP.

```
data="result": {
    "GROUP_A": {
        "statistics": {
            "year2000": 8666,
            "year2001": 1213,
            "year2002": 123,
        },
        "trending": {
            "year2000": 90,
            "year2001": 78,
            "year2002": 86,
        }
    }
    "GROUP_B": {
        "statistics": {
            "year2000": 43223,
            "year2001": 4234,
            "year2002": 124343,
        },
        "trending": {
            "year2000": 34,
            "year2001": 43,
            "year2002": 45,
        }
    }
}
```

Example output is below:

```
"result": [{
    "GROUP_A": [{
        "statistics": {
            "year2000": 8666,
            "year2001": 1213,
            "year2002": 123,
        },
        "trending": {
            "year2000": 90,
            "year2001": 78,
            "year2002": 86,
        }
    }]
    "GROUP_B": [{
        "statistics": {
            "year2000": 43223,
            "year2001": 4234,
            "year2002": 124343,
        },
        "trending": {
            "year2000": 34,
            "year2001": 43,
            "year2002": 45,
        }
    }]
}]
```

I have no idea to do. If simple object I can push like this:

```
var arr=[];
```

arr.push(data);

Reason to push into array because the key object for group is dynamic. I want to use group for filtering data.

Answer (score 2):

I did this two different ways:

1. Create an array of objects, which is common

   ```
   var array = [];

   // ARRAY OF OBJECTS
   for(i in data) {
       // Create new array above and push every object in
       array.push(data[i]);
   }
   console.log(JSON.stringify(array));
   ```
2. The way you wanted (Object with array that has arrays has objects)

   ```
   // OBJECT OF ARRAYS OF ARRAYS
   var result = data["result"];
   // Create head of object, "result"
   var obj = {"result":[]};
   var smallObj = {};
   // Push objects inside array
   for(i in result) {
       var smallArray = [];
       smallArray.push(result[i]);
       // Store that array onto array og objects, which in this case is array of arrays of objects
       smallObj[i] = smallArray;
   }
   // Final result
   obj["result"].push(smallObj);
   console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
   ```

Here is the JSFiddle so you can see the stringified version printed in the console: https://jsfiddle.net/0Loh0ucm/